# change settittle for a button to default after finish loading

Tags: ios, swift

iam trying to make my button change from login to loggin while it is loading but if UI alert appear with wrong password want to to go back to default stats which "login "

```
         isChecked = !isChecked
    if isChecked {
        sender.setTitle("login", for: .normal)

    } else {
        sender.setTitle("logging", for: .normal)
```

Here is the full code, i put the alert in else statment 
but and add break point still didnt work

```
   import UIKit
   import SwiftECP
   import XCGLogger
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var isChecked = true
@IBOutlet var UsernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var login: UIButton!

  var file1 = "file.txt"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    login.layer.cornerRadius = login.frame.height / 2
    var img = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
    view.layer.contents = img?.cgImage

  }

@IBAction func _Login(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let isFirstNameValid = checker(textField:UsernameField)
    let ispasswordValid = checker(textField:passwordField)

    isChecked = !isChecked
    if isChecked {
        sender.setTitle("login", for: .normal)

    } else {
        sender.setTitle("logging", for: .normal)
    }
    print ("text field \(isFirstNameValid)")

    if isFirstNameValid && ispasswordValid == true {
        gotourl()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            let readf = self.readFromDocumentsFile(fileName:self.file1)
            let sizefile = self.filesize(fileName:self.file1)
            if sizefile == true{
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotowelcome", sender: self)

             }
            else
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login error", message: "Wrong Username or password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                // add an action (button)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in
                    self.login.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
                    self.UsernameField.text=""
                    self.passwordField.text=""

                }))
                // show the alert
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

             }

            print("Here is the size of file \(sizefile)")
            // change 2 to desired number of seconds
            // Your code with delay
         }

      }
    else  {

        let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Login error", message: "Please enter your username and password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


func gotourl(){

let username1: String = UsernameField.text!
let password1: String = passwordField.text!
let protectedURL = URL(
    string: "https://itsapps.odu.edu/auth/getInfo.php"
    )!
let logger = XCGLogger()
logger.setup(level: .debug)

ECPLogin(
    protectedURL: protectedURL,
    username: username1,
    password: password1,
    logger: logger
    ).start { event in
        switch event {

        case let .value( body) :
            // If the request was successful, the protected resource will
            // be available in 'body'. Make sure to implement a mechanism to
            // detect authorization timeouts.

            print("Response body: \(body)")

            //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

            let text = "\(body)" //just a text
            self.writeToDocumentsFile(fileName:self.file1,value:text)


            // The Shibboleth auth cookie is now stored in the sharedHTTPCookieStorage.
            // Attach this cookie to subsequent requests to protected resources.
            // You can access the cookie with the following code:
            if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
                let shibCookie = cookies.filter { (cookie: HTTPCookie) in
                    cookie.name.range(of: "shibsession") != nil
                    }[0]
                print(shibCookie)
             }

        case let .failed(error):
            // This is an AnyError that wraps the error thrown.
            // This can help diagnose problems with your SP, your IdP, or even this library :)

            switch error.cause {
            case let ecpError as ECPError:
                // Error with ECP
                // User-friendly error message
                print(ecpError.userMessage)

                // Technical/debug error message
                print(ecpError.description)
            case let alamofireRACError as AlamofireRACError:
                // Error with the networking layer
                print(alamofireRACError.description)
            default:
                print("Unknown error!")
                print(error)

            }

        default:
            break

        }
  }

  }

func filesize(fileName:String) -> Bool {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let attributes = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath:path)
    let fileSize = attributes[.size] as! NSNumber
    if fileSize != 0 {
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }

  }

func checker(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    guard (!textField.text!.isEmpty) else {
        return false
    }
    return true
  }
func writeToDocumentsFile(fileName:String,value:String) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do{
        try value.write(toFile: path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    }catch{
    }
    }

func readFromDocumentsFile(fileName:String) -> String {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let checkValidation = FileManager.default
    var file:String

    if checkValidation.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        do{
            try file = NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String
            print ("Here is what is in file \(file)")
        }catch{
            file = ""
        }
    } else {
        file = ""
    }

    return file
 }


}


    }
```

in anther part of my code

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login error", message: "Wrong Username or password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in
                    self.UsernameField.text=""
                    self.passwordField.text=""
                    sender.setTitle("login", for: .normal)

                }))
```

but still not working anyidea why?

Comment: you must use something like `self.buttonLogin.setTitle("login", for: .normal)` I think that sender is a parameter in your first code example and is not available in your second code example chunk of code

Comment: i even tried that didnt work.

Comment: Your alert is not showing at all or just the button is not being changed?

Comment: no button not changing, the alert is showing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you lose the reference to the button and the has to be loaded again when the popup appears or something funky like that happens.

Since there are two states only a simple solution is to have the default text for the button be "login" and when you want to change it then don't do it in the closure because it is a weak outlet.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: Okay I just want to check some stuff first
-Why don't you have an outlet to the button?
-Is the second bit of code inside the else of the condition?

Comment: i do have outlet for it but code is little big and yes the second part of code inside ... wanna me to share whole code?

Comment: Okay so from what I understand so far is that you want to display loggin while it's loading and when it fails it goes back to login so just replace the 

            sender.setTitle("login", for: .normal)

and use self.buttonOutlet.setTitle instead inside the closure and it should work and also I've noticed you don't display the alert in this bit of code yet

Comment: Okay so first thing I notice is that your outlets should probably be weak vars and also I don't see the part where you use the outlet of the button to change the title back to login in the alert.

Comment: // add an action (button)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in
                    self.login.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
                    self.UsernameField.text=""
                    self.passwordField.text=""

                }))

Comment: So the code is working (after I stripped away all the requests and stuff) so that means the problem is in your conditions so I recommend you check for the values and print them. Also breakpoints will help you and don't forget to change the outlets to weak vars. And don't compare two bool values with one as ( isFirstNameValid && ispasswordValid == true ) it's weird to see as you should compare both of them in the same way if they are both bools like this (isFirstNameValid && ispasswordValid)

Comment: so the part when it is not working , is when you hit login without fill the username and password text field. after ui alert show the button should back to login not stay to logging

Answer (score 0):

Did you present the alert? The above code works for me after I added

`self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

The full code:

```
@IBAction func loginFailedButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login error", message: "Wrong Username or password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in
            self.usernameField.text=""
            self.passwordField.text=""
            print("foo")
            sender.setTitle("login", for: .normal)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Update:

```
It looks like the issue is there in the following lines:
let sizefile = self.filesize(fileName:self.file1)
                if sizefile == true{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotowelcome", sender: self)

                }
                else
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login error", message: "Wrong Username or password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    // add an action (button)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in
                        self.login.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
                        self.UsernameField.text=""
                        self.passwordField.text=""

                    }))
```

If i set `let sizefile = false //self.filesize(fileName:self.file1)`

The code does go to else, and *the alert works as required*.

There is no issue with your alert controller, seems like `func filesize(fileName:String)` is always returning true, hence it never goes to the else condition. You need to fix that function.

Comment: it doesnt work for me, dunno why !! i guess cause iam putting alert in else statement

Comment: Try putting break points and see if this part of the code is reachable. If it's not, then post more code. We can try and fix it from there.

Comment: add break point to "            sender.setTitle("login", for: .normal)" but it dont reach it .. will add the whole code now.

Comment: Added an update. Let me know if that helps. I do not know what your FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath:path) returns, so can't really fix that.

Comment: ok but what is the file manager had to do with the button?  
the alert control appear when the login and password field is empty.

Comment: When i clicked login button when the ussrname and password fields were empty, it did show me the alert controller. It went to the last else code.